# Fit Row of TableLayoutPanel if this is the container of a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tablelayoutpanel

[image: form with TableLayoutPanel]

I have a Form with a TabPage Control.
Each TabPage has a Tablelayoutpanel as you can see in the attached image.

Tablelayoutpanel has `AutoScroll = True` (I disable the horizontal scroll by code).
Tablelayoutpanel size is `1209x372` pixels.

My Tablelayoutpanel has 1 column and 6 rows.
The first and third row has a label (title) inside.
The second and fourth rows contain a DataGridView.

Rows with a label have a "absolute" size of `21` pixels.

The issue is with the height of the Panels that host the DataGridView Controls.

I have tried with `SizeType` set to `Automatic` or `Percentage`, but the Panels does not resize to the size of the DataGridViews when the DataSource is set.
It works fine if I put an absolute size for each Panel, but then I have to try with several pixel sizes. I do it manually.

I think the reason why "Automatic" or "Percentage" don´t make sense in this case is because the height of the DataGridViews may be greater than the height of the TablelayoutPanel control.
The Datagridviews have `AutoScroll = False`, always.

I have read that this is the priority:

When the TableLayoutPanel control arranges its rows, it assigns priorities to each RowStyle in the following order:

1. Rows with RowStyle set to Absolute are considered first and assigned their fixed heights.
2. Rows with RowStyle set to AutoSize have the size of their content.
3. The remaining space is divided between rows with the RowStyle set to Percent.

Then I did this (by code in runtime):

```
private void RedimensionaDatagrid(TableLayoutPanel tlp,int indiceRowPanel, DataGridView dtgv)
{
    dtgv.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
    dtgv.RowsDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;  
    int alturaTotalDatagrid = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtgv.Rows)
    {
        alturaTotalDatagrid += row.Height;
    }

    TableLayoutRowStyleCollection styles =
    tlp.RowStyles;
    styles[indiceRowPanel].SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;

    styles[indiceRowPanel].Height = alturaTotalDatagrid;
    dtgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
}
```

This does not work fine if that code snippet is located in the form_load event.

If I put that code inside a button, once the form is loaded and I press the button, it works perfect.

I have added that code in the form_Show event but it happens the same that form_load.

Take into account that I use: DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells, so the default height (22 pixels) is not correct. I must get the result height of each row once the datagridview has DataSource.

I would like to do that action (code snippet) without pressing the button, just when the form is loading or showing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Panel that hosts the DataGridView should be set to auto-size, so it will expand the Row of a TableLayoutPanel that is also set to auto-size. If you want to automatically expand vertically a DataGridView, to show all of its content, use the `[DataGridView].PreferredSize.Height`. You may need to subtract `SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight` if the DGV is not anchored. Otherwise, anchor the DGV Top/Left/Right (so it expands only vertically, so does the hosting Panel). I.e., don't dock it to automate the layout.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that Controls placed on a TabPage other than the first visible, don't create their handles until the TabPage is shown. Some functionalities are not active until a Control's handle is created.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Jimi.
I did that in Runtime (during loading form and it works)

AutoSize for DataGridView and AutoSize for RowPanel.

["row" gap in the end of the panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Inis.png)

However, if you see the attached picture, it seems that the DatagridView does not end in the end of the RowPanel, there is a little gap.